# How to write a method in ruby that takes hash-style, square bracketed arguments, like mymethod[arg]?

Tags: ruby, methods, syntax

I want to write a method in ruby to replace a current method that simply returns a hash.

So currently we have this

```
def some_stats
  {
    :foo => "bar",
    :zoo => "zar"
  }
end
```

which can be called like this:

```
some_stats[:foo]
```

I want to replace this with a method that is called with :foo, which does some more complicated things that just building a hash.  However, I'd like it to be called in the same way, with the square bracket notation.  EG

```
#this is a bit pseudo-cody but hopefully you get the idea.
def some_stats[](key)
  if key.to_s =~ /something/
    #do something
    return something
  else
    #do something else
    return something_else
  end
end
```

This would still be called like `some_stats[:foo]`

I can't work out the syntax for defining the method name:  the above, `def some_stats[](key)` doesn't work.  I feel like this should be possible though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're quite close. `object[sth]` is just a syntax sugar for `object.[](sth)`. So to do what you need you have to define `some_stats` method that returns the object which defines `[]` method:

```
class Stats
  def [](key)
    if key.to_s =~ /something/
     #do something
     return something
  else
    #do something else
    return something_else
  end
end

def some_stats
  Stats.new
end

some_stats[:something_new] #=> something
some_stats[:not_new] #=> something_else
```

Answer (score 3):

Your original method is not **called with square brackets**; it is called **without any argument**, but returns an object (in your case a `Hash`), which has method `:[]` defined and hence understands square brackets. Your method call is equivalent to

```
(some_stats())[:foo]
```

or, more explicitly, to

```
x = some_stats()
x[:foo]
```

Therefore you need - inside your method return an instance of some class which offers the `[]` method. Say you have written a class named `MyClass` which has a `[]` defined. You could then write a function

```
def some_stats
  if _your condition goes here_
    { ... } # Return your Hash
  else
    Myclass.new
  end
end
```

This would be used as

```
some_stats[:whatever]
```

However, to be really useful, your condition would make use of a parameter to the method, i.e.

```
def some_stats(param)
  if param < 4000
    { ... } # Return your Hash
  else
    Myclass.new
  end
end
```

And you would invoke it by

```
some_stats(4711)[:whatever]
```

Comment: `some_stats` could also return a lambda if there is a little bit of processing that needs to be done but not enough for a whole class.